# Как лучше преобразовывать List<T> в ObservableCollection<T> и наоборот?

Tags: c#, list, observablecollection

Я это делаю так:

1. Создаю новый `ObservableCollection<T>`
2. Перебираю `List<T>` в `foreach` и на каждой итерации добавляю в `ObservableCollection` элемент `List`;

Мне кажется это не "шик". Как эту задачу сделать "шиковой"?

---

Будет ли хорошим вариантом написание **Extension** для такого дела?

Comment: Вообще очень странный вопрос, зачем вам подобное вообще понадобилось? В приложение обычно  либо сразу используется ObservableCollection и туда добавляются поочередно элементы, либо если необязательно обновлять интерфейс, то используют сразу List<> без всяких преобразований и прочего. Ну а вообще - `new List<string>(observable)` ну и `new ObservableCollection<string>(list)` соответственно.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, пишет нельзя преобразовать типы.

Comment: И какой у вас тип? Вот вам [пример](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WQ2oVD), как видите все успешно отрабатывает.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, извините! Я не вчитался в синтаксис). Вы правы. Всё работает. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По сути тут все зависит от того, как именно вы будете обрабатывать эти объекты.

- Если просто надо сделать из `List<T>` `ObservableCollection<T>`, то можем посмотреть документацию ([`List<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.-ctor) [`ObservableCollection<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1.-ctor)) и сразу будет видно, что мы можем просто передать через конструктор нужный `IEnumerable<T>`).

  ```
  var list = new List<string>();
  var observable = new ObservableCollection<string>(list);
  ```
- Если же у вас есть некая логика преобразования, то тут уже можно сделать и `Extension` метод, который вернет нам указанный тип. Например создадим метод расширения, который вернет `ObservableCollection<T>` и в качестве логики мы сделаем так, чтобы он вернул только N элементов, взятых у входного списка:

  ```
  static class Extensions
  {
      public static ObservableCollection<T> TakeToObservable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, int count) 
          => new ObservableCollection<T>(enumerable.Take(count));
  }
  ```

  Использование:

  ```
  var observable = new List<string>().TakeToObservable(10);
  ```

В общем смотрите сами, как вам именно нужно реализовать.
Удачи в изучении C#!